# PHP $_POST to http but redirects to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to switch my page to https using a .htaccess, however the problem is that someone is posting data to me on the http page. When they post the data and my server 301 redirects them to the https page, the request is lost.

Is there a workaround with this?

Comment: ENCRYPT ALL THE THINGS! If you have an SSL Cert, then change everything to use the HTTPS protocol. There is no draw back in this case, and you're only further securing your users data anyway.